# VBA sheet1$ error message

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm using a macro to pull data from one worksheet to another but I keep receiving the error "The microsoft access database engine could not find the object 'sheet1$'". I know for sure that the referenced file has Sheet1 and the path is correct. What may be the problem is that the multiple referenced files were created in the same workbook and saved as separate files afterward. So when I open one of the referenced files it's displayed as, say, Sheet2343(Sheet1) and that's what I think creates the problem- the macro is looking for Sheet1 in the workbook but finds only Sheet2343 and therefore return an error message. Below is the code I'm using. Could anyone,please, suggest a workaround?

Thanks!

```
Sub Pull_Data()

Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset

rsFile$ = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("C1") & ".xlsx"
strConn$ = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & rsFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"

rsSQL$ = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset

rsData.Open rsSQL, strConn, , adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified
Sheet1.Range("F4").CopyFromRecordset rsData

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to copy the let's say Sheet2343? Or only files that have explicitly Sheet1? Does the file has only one sheet? Does the sheet has an unique title that may work as unique identifier for the sheet?

Comment: So each file would only have one worksheet called Sheet1- so maybe it's possible to tweak the macro so it pulls the data from that sheet in the referenced workbook. Thanks!

Comment: You can discover the actual sheet name(s) using Siddharth's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982990/iterate-through-excel-worksheet-names-when-office-not-installed-using-vb6

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: for your use case something like this

```
Sub Pull_Data()

    Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset, sheetName
    Dim rsFile As String, strConn, rsSQL

    rsFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("C1") & ".xlsx"

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & rsFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"

    sheetName = GetSheetName(rsFile) 

    rsSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "]"
    Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset

    rsData.Open rsSQL, strConn, , adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified
    Sheet1.Range("F4").CopyFromRecordset rsData

End Sub

'return the worksheet name from a closed single-sheet Excel file
Function GetSheetName(fPath As String)
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsT As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fPath & _
                      ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With
    Set rsT = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    GetSheetName = rsT.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value
    rsT.Close: Set rsT = Nothing
    cn.Close: Set cn = Nothing
End Function
```

Here's how to use ADOX to query the structure of an Excel workbook:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsT As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim intTblCnt As Integer, intTblFlds As Integer
    Dim strTbl As String
    Dim rsC As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim intColCnt As Integer, intColFlds As Integer
    Dim strCol As String
    Dim t As Integer, c As Integer, f As Integer

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cn
        'edit: updated to work with .xlsx-format files
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & _
                   "\ADOXSource.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With

    Set rsT = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)

    intTblCnt = rsT.RecordCount
    intTblFlds = rsT.Fields.Count

    Debug.Print "Tables:  " & intTblCnt
    Debug.Print "--------------------"

    For t = 1 To intTblCnt

        strTbl = rsT.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value

        Debug.Print vbTab & "Table #" & t & ":    " & strTbl
        Debug.Print vbTab & "--------------------"

        For f = 0 To intTblFlds - 1
            Debug.Print vbTab & rsT.Fields(f).Name & _
                        vbTab & rsT.Fields(f).Value
        Next

        Debug.Print "--------------------"
        Set rsC = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
                     Array(Empty, Empty, strTbl, Empty))

        intColCnt = rsC.RecordCount
        intColFlds = rsC.Fields.Count

        For c = 1 To intColCnt
            strCol = rsC.Fields("COLUMN_NAME").Value
            Debug.Print vbTab & vbTab & "Column #" & c & ": " & strCol
            Debug.Print vbTab & vbTab & "--------------------"
            For f = 0 To intColFlds - 1
                Debug.Print vbTab & vbTab & rsC.Fields(f).Name & _
                            vbTab & rsC.Fields(f).Value
            Next
            Debug.Print vbTab & vbTab & "--------------------"
            rsC.MoveNext
        Next

        rsC.Close
        Debug.Print "--------------------"
        rsT.MoveNext
    Next
    rsT.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the reply. So should I use the code above instead of the one that I have now or should they both be used in the same macro? I'm still very new to VBA. Thanks!

Comment: Do all of the files you need to read from only have a single sheet?

Comment: Awesome, very nice Tim!

Comment: @RyanWildry - likely I just stole that from somewhere else, but so long ago I don't recall  ;-)

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that the way my macro works is that it references to column C1 that stores the name of the file data of which should be extracted in column F4. So say column C1 is ID_23435 then the macro would extract the data from the file named ID_23435 (and located in the same folder) in column F4.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the codes. However, when I run it it gives me the 3021 run-time error "vba either bof or eof is true or the current record has been deleted". But I think there should be record in the database to match the query.

Comment: GetSheetName = rsT.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value

Comment: Any chance you can share a workbook which shows that problem?

Answer (score 0):

My original issue was caused by not noticing that there was a space after a certain string. Simple as that but took me some time to figure that out. Thank you all for your valuable inputs!